# KeyError: "None of [Index(["", ""], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [www.oddsportal.com/soccer](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer) and this is my unit test that works:

[html sample data](https://pastebin.com/fmu4Y6Vu)

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Sample HTML data
html_data_1 = """
"""

html_data_2 = """
"""

html_data_3 = """
"""

html_data_4 = """
"""

html_data_5 = """
"""
# HTML strings
html_data_list = [html_data_1, html_data_2, html_data_3, html_data_4, html_data_5]

# Using lxml and XPath
tree = html.fromstring(html_data_1)

# Extracting the date from the header
date = tree.xpath('//h1[@id="next-matches-h1"]/text()')[0]

# Splitting the date string to get the date part
date = date.split(", ")[-1]

data = []

# Initialize initial values for Country and League
current_country = None
current_league = None


# Iterate through each HTML string in the list
for html_str in html_data_list:
    # Using lxml and XPath
    tree = html.fromstring(html_str)

    # Extracting match rows
    match_rows = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "eventRow")]')

    # Iterate through each match row
    for match_row in match_rows:
        country = match_row.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "font-normal")]/p[contains(@class, "truncate")]/text()')
        league = match_row.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "truncate")]/text()')
        
        if country:
            current_country = country[0].strip()
        else:
            country = [current_country]
        
        if league:
            current_league = league[0].strip()
        else:
            league = [current_league]

        team_elements = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-16416b72]/a[@title]')
        game_teams = [element.xpath('.//p[@class="participant-name truncate"]/text()')[0].strip() for element in team_elements]
        game_teams_str = " - ".join(game_teams)  # Combine the team names
        time = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-d99de4de]/p/text()')[0].strip()
        score = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-16416b72]/@r-e-s-u-l-t')[0]
        odds = match_row.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "min-w-[60px]")]/div/p[@data-v-44bd9554]/text()')

        # Append extracted data to the data list
        data.append({
            "Country": country[0],  # Take the first element as the value
            "League": league[0],    # Take the first element as the value
            "Date": date,
            "Time": time,
            "Game": game_teams_str,
            "Score": score,
            "Home Odds": odds[0],
            "Draw Odds": odds[1],
            "Away Odds": odds[2]
        })

# Create a DataFrame from the data list
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Fill down the Country and League columns
df[['Country', 'League']] = df[['Country', 'League']].ffill()
```

print df:

```
+---+---------------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   |     Date      | Time  |  Country  |     League     |                  Game                  | Score | Home Odds | Draw Odds | Away Odds |
+---+---------------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 0 | Today, 01 Sep | 00:00 | Argentina | Reserve League | Arsenal Sarandi 2 - Barracas Central 2 |  1-0  |   2.23    |   3.17    |   3.11    |
| 1 | Today, 01 Sep | 00:00 | Argentina | Reserve League |  San Lorenzo 2 - Union de Santa Fe 2   |  1-1  |   1.56    |   3.75    |   5.82    |
| 2 | Today, 01 Sep | 00:00 | Argentina | Reserve League |   Estudiantes L.P. 2 - Racing Club 2   |  1-2  |   2.28    |   3.15    |   3.05    |
| 3 | Today, 01 Sep | 00:00 | Argentina | Reserve League |            Ilves W - KuPS W            |  1-6  |   18.64   |   14.83   |   1.03    |
+---+---------------+-------+-----------+----------------+----------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now, I modified this code to my scraper that cycles through webpages of the webiste as:

```
import os
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import nan
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re
from lxml import html

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 30000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
start = datetime.now()
today = datetime.today().strftime('%d %b %Y')



class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []

# Updated generate_matches function using lxml and XPath
def generate_matches(html_data_list, defaultVal=None):
    data = []
    # Initialize initial values for Country and League
    current_country = None
    current_league = None

    # Iterate through each HTML string in the list
    for html_str in html_data_list:
        # Using lxml and XPath
        tree = html.fromstring(html_str)

        # Extracting match rows
        match_rows = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "eventRow")]')

        # Iterate through each match row
        for match_row in match_rows:
            country = match_row.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "font-normal")]/p[contains(@class, "truncate")]/text()')
            league = match_row.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "truncate")]/text()')

            if country:
                current_country = country[0].strip()
            else:
                country = [current_country]

            if league:
                current_league = league[0].strip()
            else:
                league = [current_league]

            team_elements = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-16416b72]/a[@title]')
            game_teams = [element.xpath('.//p[@class="participant-name truncate"]/text()')[0].strip() for element in team_elements]
            game_teams_str = " - ".join(game_teams)  # Combine the team names

            time_element = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-d99de4de]/p/text()')
            time_match = re.search(r"(\d{2}:\d{2})", time_element[0])
            time_str = time_match.group(1) if time_match else ""

            date_element = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-d99de4de]/p/text()')
            date_match = re.search(r"\d{1,2} \w+", date_element[0])
            date_str = today if 'Today' in date_element[0] else date_match.group() if date_match else ""

            score_element = match_row.xpath('.//div[@data-v-16416b72]/@r-e-s-u-l-t')
            score_str = score_element[0]

            odds_elements = match_row.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "min-w-[60px]")]/div/p[@data-v-44bd9554]/text()')

            # Append extracted data to the data list
            data.append({
                "Country": country[0],  # Take the first element as the value
                "League": league[0],    # Take the first element as the value
                "Date": date_str,
                "Time": time_str,
                "Game": game_teams_str,
                "Score": score_str,
                "Home Odds": odds_elements[0],
                "Draw Odds": odds_elements[1],
                "Away Odds": odds_elements[2]
            })

    return data



def parse_data(url):
    print(f'Parsing URL: {url}\n')
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    # Wait for the first match element to be present
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    match_element_class = "border-black-borders.group.flex"  # Class of the match element
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f".{match_element_class}")))

    # Now, check if the first match element contains match data
    first_match_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f".{match_element_class}")
    match_data_indicator = "participant-name"  # Class indicating match data
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, match_data_indicator)))
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    scroll_pause_time = 4

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    html_data_list = [str(soup)]

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    html_str = browser.page_source
    for row in generate_matches([html_str], defaultVal=nan):  # Pass the list of HTML strings
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    return game_data, html_data_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_data = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    url_to_parse = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data, html_data_list = parse_data(url_to_parse)
    if game_data is not None:
        df = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        # Fill down the Country and League columns
        df[['Country', 'League']] = df[['Country', 'League']].ffill()
        # Print the entire DataFrame
        print(df)

    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance
    import gc

    gc.collect()
```

I get the error:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Country', 'League'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I can see `html_data_list` has the html in str however i am not getting any table.

What is the correct way to incorporate the test case in my code?

Comment: Maybe trailing white spaces? do `print(df.columns)?